# EOSFLARE API Request

Tags: cleos, api, python, block-explorer

I'm trying to test the APIs I've found on [eosflare](https://eosflare.io/api) because I need to find some blocks and transactions information for my thesis.

I was wondering if I could retrieve the data without downloading **cleos** with a simple API Request. I think the API url is someway correct because I get this response when I test it:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.eosflare.io/v1/eosflare/get_account/')
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.encoding)
print(r.text)
```

```
200
application/json; charset=utf-8
utf-8
{"err_code":10,"err_msg":"Error: ($.account: undefined) ✖ (required: true)"}
```

But when I try to add an account name to solve the previous error, I always get a *Not Found* response:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.eosflare.io/v1/eosflare/get_account/yupcreators1')
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.encoding)
print(r.text)
```

```
404
text/plain; charset=utf-8
utf-8
Not Found
```

Thanks in advance for any type of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation here:

https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/plugins/chain_api_plugin/api-reference/index#operation/get_account

You must send the account name in POST request (not a GET)

```
{"account_name": "nameofaccount"}
```

Example:

```
curl -d '{"account_name": "hackerdarwin"}' http://api.eosn.io/v1/chain/get_account
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to get information about an account. I'm now having prolems with the `get_actions` method, I'll make a new question if needed I guess.